# Speed up calculation of partitions in Haskell

Tags: performance, haskell, math, number-theory

I'm trying to solve Euler problem 78, which basically asks for the first number where the [partition function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_%28number_theory%29) p(n) is divisible by 1000000.

I use Euler's recursive fomula based on pentagonal numbers (calculated here in `pents` together with the proper sign). Here is my code:

```
ps = 1 : map p [1..] where
  p n = sum $ map getP $ takeWhile ((<= n).fst) pents where
    getP (pent,sign) = sign * (ps !! (n-pent)) 

pents = zip (map (\n -> (3*n-1)*n `div` 2) $ [1..] >>= (\x -> [x,-x]))
            (cycle [1,1,-1,-1])
```

While `ps` seems to produce the correct results, it is too slow. Is there a way to speed the calculation up, or do I need a completely different approach?

Comment: With hammar's idea and Chris Kuklewicz's advice not to use ghci, it seems that my solution is practical enough.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`xs !! n` has a linear complexity. You should rather try using a logarithmic or constant-access data structure.

Edit : here is a quick implementation I came up with by copying [a similar one by augustss](http://www.reddit.com/r/haskell/comments/f4nba/question_about_memoizing_a_recursive_function/c1d99up) :

```
psOpt x = psArr x
  where psCall 0 = 1
        psCall n = sum $ map getP $ takeWhile ((<= n).fst) pents where
          getP (pent,sign) = sign * (psArr (n-pent))
        psArr n = if n > ncache then psCall n else psCache ! n
        psCache = listArray (0,ncache) $ map psCall [0..ncache]
```

In ghci, I observe no spectacular speedup over your list version. No luck !

**Edit :**
Indeed, with `-O2` as suggested by Chris Kuklewicz, this solution is eight times faster than your for `n=5000`. Combined with Hammar insight of doing sums modulo 10^6, I get a solution that is fast enough (find the hopefully correct answer in about 10 seconds on my machine):

```
import Data.List (find)
import Data.Array 

ps = 1 : map p [1..] where
  p n = sum $ map getP $ takeWhile ((<= n).fst) pents where
    getP (pent,sign) = sign * (ps !! (n-pent)) 

summod li = foldl (\a b -> (a + b) `mod` 10^6) 0 li

ps' = 1 : map p [1..] where
  p n = summod $ map getP $ takeWhile ((<= n).fst) pents where
    getP (pent,sign) = sign * (ps !! (n-pent)) 

ncache = 1000000

psCall 0 = 1
psCall n = summod $ map getP $ takeWhile ((<= n).fst) pents
  where getP (pent,sign) = sign * (psArr (n-pent))
psArr n = if n > ncache then psCall n else psCache ! n
psCache = listArray (0,ncache) $ map psCall [0..ncache]

pents = zip (map (\n -> ((3*n-1)*n `div` 2) `mod` 10^6) $ [1..] >>= (\x -> [x,-x]))
            (cycle [1,1,-1,-1])
```

(I broke the psCache abstraction, so you should use `psArr` instead of `psOpt`; this ensures that different call to `psArr` will reuse the same memoized array. This is useful when you write `find ((== 0) . ...)`... well, I thought it was better not to publish the *complete* solution.)

Thanks to all for the additional advice.

Comment: ghci is not fast enough for big Euler problems.  You need to actually compile with 'ghc -O2'

Answer (score 2):

Well, one observation is that since you're only interested in `` map (`mod` 10^6) ps ``, you might be able to avoid having to do calculations on huge numbers.

Comment: That is a good trick, but it turns out that this peculiar challenge  can be solved without this optimization.

Comment: True, but it applies to a lot of PE problems. One favorite trick of mine is to define a newtype with a Num instance that does modular arithmetic. That way I can reuse a lot of existing code.

Comment: @Chris Kuklewicz I tested with my Array implementation, the modular trick speeds up the computation of p(n) for "the right n" from 40s to 15s on my machine. Not fundamental, but still pretty nice.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't done that Euler problem, but usually with Euler problems there is a clever trick to speed up the calculation.

When I see this:

```
sum $ map getP $ takeWhile ((<=n).fst) pents
```

I can't help but think there must be a smarter way than to invoke `sum . map getP` every time you compute an element of `ps`.

Now that I look at it...wouldn't it be faster to perform the sum first, and then multiply, rather than performing the multiply (inside of `getP`) for every element and *then* summing?

Normally I'd take a deeper look and provide working code; but it's an Euler problem (wouldn't want to spoil it!), so I'll just stop here with these few thoughts.

Comment: How can you perform the sum first and then multiply? It's not the same. ax+by ≠ (a+b)(x+y)… unless you're thinking of something else that I didn't understand?

Comment: Oh you're right; for some reason I was thinking that `sign` was the same for all of them, so that cx+cy = c(x+y), but it's not the same. My mistake. It might be faster to use `id` and `negate` instead of `*1` and `*-1` respectively, though that would be a minor speedup at best.

Answer (score 1):

Inspired by your question, I have used your approach to solve Euler 78 with Haskell.  So I can give you some performance hints.

Your cached list of pents should be good as it is.

Pick some large number maxN to bound your search for (p n).

The plan is to use an (Array Int64 Integer) to memorize the result of (p n), with lower bound 0 and upper bound maxN.  This requires defining the array in terms of 'p' and 'p' in terms of the array, they are mutually recursively defined:

Redefine (p n) to (pArray n) to look up recursive calls to 'p' in the array A.

Use your new pArray with Data.Array.IArray.listArray to create the array A.

Definitely compile with 'ghc -O2'.  This runs in 13 seconds here.

Comment: Using the trick of doing the math modulo 1000000 drops the runtime to 4.4 seconds.